Is there an official name for the "number generator" tests at the begining of Longlegs?
In the movie, Longlegs, FBI agent Lee Harker undergoes a series of tests while sitting in front of a flickering projector screen, organised by the FBI.
She is presented with a number of still images and she has to say out aloud that what she really sees from these abstract images, one of them is a triangle and she responds with "father". The second part of this test is to look at another group of abstract still images and say which number each one of them represents from 0 to 100 inclusive.
Do they have an official name for this kind of tests? Or is it more or less made up?

The CIA did experiments with clairvoyance, telepathy, mind control, etc. I don't think any serious scientists ever came up with a standardized test, let alone a name for one.

Sounds like a version of a Rorschach test

They are called projective tests:

a projective test is a personality test designed to let a person respond to ambiguous stimuli, presumably revealing hidden emotions and internal conflicts projected by the person into the test.
[..]
The responses to projective tests are content analyzed for meaning rather than being based on presuppositions about meaning, as is the case with objective tests.

Famous real-world examples are the Rorschach inkblot test (mentioned by Paulie_D), and the word association test, in which a single word or verb is used to illicit associations (based on free association).
I can imagine the first test you mention having some kind of use to assess psychological aptitude (it doesn't seem  much different from the Rorschach or Holtzman tests), but the second one seems more (visually) interesting than useful.
